# Writers Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :D

Comment: **Thanks for your help and time, everyone!**

Answer (score 4):

[Can you change a punctuation mark when referencing a passage from a text?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/can-you-change-a-punctuation-mark-when-referencing-a-passage-from-a-text)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Excellent question - clear, concise, and practical. Answer is clear and has a reference.

Answer (score 3):

[What are the legal implications and best practices for publishing screenshots of web sites in a book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5720/what-are-the-legal-implications-and-best-practices-for-publishing-screenshots-of)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Legal question, but clear, useful, and with as great an answer as one could hope short of a direct legal ruling :)

Comment: A fairly wide problem, with applicability to a range of non-fiction work. And a good answer indicating the route someone needs to take to do this.

Answer (score 3):

[My cool character is doing nothing for the plot. How do I deal with him?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5705/my-cool-character-is-doing-nothing-for-the-plot-how-do-i-deal-with-him)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Oy. On the one hand, yay - an immediate practical problem faced by OP! On the other hand - as [my answer](http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/5717/1046) implies, IMHO we don't have anywhere _near_ enough detail to provide a reliable diagnosis (which is what's requested). And sufficient detail would likely be cumbersome and "too localized." I feel this problem would do better as a discussion or with direct critique. This makes me a little bit sad. No vote.

Comment: This is one that I think is tricky for the site. There are a number of options in the answers, and so as a Q and A, it seems to provide a lot of useful information. Having said that, it is not a straightforward simple answer to a Question. I like this because it does give a lot of options, so others can see these options and then work out what they need to do in their situation.

Comment: The answers for this are awesome.  Sometimes SE's advice on some questions has been "create the canonical question which all others that relate will be closed as a dupe of."  I don't think we'll actually get duplicates of this question, but it is kind of a canonical question based on the answers it has, and I think a good sell for our site, even if we don't want *too* many others like it.

Answer (score 2):

[What binding and paper should be used on a self-printed novel?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/what-binding-and-paper-should-be-used-on-a-self-printed-novel)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question that may have broader applicability than one might think.  The answer by Jed is great.

Answer (score 2):

[What is the proper way to add Creative Commons licensing information to a book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-creative-commons-licensing-information-to-a-book)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Practical legal + formatting question, with good answers.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I maintain flow and interest when handling numerous plot threads?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5669/how-do-i-maintain-flow-and-interest-when-handling-numerous-plot-threads)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I like the answers to this one, but the question itself needs fleshing out.  It's a common problem, but the question (even as edited) could still use help.

Comment: So-so, both the question and the answers.

Answer (score -1):

[Do I have to revise my book on paper?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5707/do-i-have-to-revise-my-book-on-paper)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Neh. "Is this guideline a _rule_? How many Hemmingway Points do I lose if I don't want to do this? Is it _always_ true that guidelines aren't always true?". My pardons to OP, but this particular question comes across as being unbearably amateurish. "I've heard guideline X, is it a **rule**?" is a horrible template for a question.

Comment: It also stank a little of *whine* "This is hard work! I don't wanna do it! Do I *haaaaaaave* to?"

Comment: @LaurenIpsum We should get him some cheese for his *whine*. /me runs away

Comment: @Aarthi hee hee hee Parmesan me, but that was brie-lliant! A really gouda joke! Definitely cheddar than anything I would have come up with.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Hee hee hee!

Comment: @LaurenIpsum - ah. ma. zing.

Answer (score -1):

[What is the name for the literary technique where the author writes him/herself into a book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/what-is-the-name-for-the-literary-technique-where-the-author-writes-him-herself)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Kind of a "neh" question, "what is the name of this technique" - kind of using SE as a lexicon. But the answer is good, both thorough and concise.

Comment: Good answer but a poor question gets a downvote from me.

Answer (score -1):

[How to effectively jump from one period of time to another in a short story?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/how-to-effectively-jump-from-one-period-of-time-to-another-in-a-short-story)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Middling question, using critique questions to solicit a judgement call rather than solve a problem. Answer is terse and limited to the most formal definition of the question - correct, but not very helpful or comprehensive.

Answer (score -4):

[website to publish article on high-performance cluster computing?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/website-to-publish-article-on-high-performance-cluster-computing)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It seems very specific, which means there is probably a really good clear and simple answer somewhere. But for anyone else looking for more general advice, it probably wont work.

Comment: way too localized for us.